# Designing a comic style border for input element

Tags: html, css

How can I design a rectangular shape to cover an input element in html as a border, but I want to design this in a comic style. e.g. The right outer border should be broader than the left and the top right corner should be sharp and pointing out like something comic style.

Comment: [Pick one](https://www.google.com/search?q=css3+chat+bubble)

Comment: please go through this link, it may felp u.. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Answer (score 1):

A comic border is a really cool idea. I thought of two ideas on how to get this look.

- You can use `border-image:` in css. You can find more info at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp.
- I also found a codepen that has cool comic book borders, https://codepen.io/mp/pen/ldAFs. They achieve the look of the comic book borders by rotating the div with the border, and rotating and inner div. This gives the div a crooked look, and the borders are tapered.

I hope this answer helps you!

Comment: Thanks Pete ! but this is not something i was looking for. Thanks again.!